# Create map after get information of location through AJAX

Tags: ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to get the longitude and latitude of a location from a text file through AJAX then create a map using that information. This is what I have done:

```
function createMap(){

var request;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

if (request)
{
    var number = Math.floor( (Math.random() * 3) + 1 );

    var url = "text_" + number + ".txt";

    request.open("GET", url,true);

    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
        {
        var syd=new google.maps.LatLng(-33.884183, 151.214944);
        var woll=new google.maps.LatLng(request.responseText);
        function initialize()
        {
            var mapProp = {
                    center:syd,
                    zoom:6,
                    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("outputAJAX"),mapProp);

            var myTrip=[syd,woll];
            var flightPath=new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path:myTrip,
                    strokeColor:"#0000FF",
                    strokeOpacity:0.8,
                    strokeWeight:2
                    });

            flightPath.setMap(map);
        }

            initialize();
        }
    }

    request.send();

} else {

    document.getElementById("outputAJAX").innerHTML = "<span style='font-weight:bold;'>AJAX</span> is not supported by this browser!";
}}
```

However, the map didn't show up. Do you guys have any suggestion?

Comment: What is `response.request.Text`?

Comment: I have 3 text files that have longitude and latitude of 3 different places like this: 
`-31.946922, 115.853511`
`-34.424299, 150.885959`
`-37.854861, 145.052150`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [google.maps.LatLng object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) takes two *Numbers* as its arguments:

```
LatLng(lat:number, lng:number, noWrap?:boolean) Creates a LatLng object representing a geographic point. Latitude is specified in degrees within the range [-90, 90]. Longitude is specified in degrees within the range [-180, 180]. Set noWrap to true to enable values outside of this range. Note the ordering of latitude and longitude.
```

This won't work (you are only passing one argument, a string):

```
var woll=new google.maps.LatLng(request.responseText);
```

Assuming `request.responseText` is a comma separated string containing two numeric values, this should work:

```
var coordStr = request.responseText;
var coords = coordStr.split(",");
var woll = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]),
                                  parseFloat(coords[1]));
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/j8mgvp1y/)

Comment: Thanks, I think you pointed out one of the problems.
However, when I added it to my code, it still didnt work
My question is, can it run with AJAX?

Comment: Should be able to.  What errors are you getting now?  What is the value of `request.responseText` inside the callback function?  What does your HTML look like?

Comment: I didnt get any errors. I'm using xampp and try to run my code with it. And the value of request.responseText is the string taken from the text files

Comment: my HTML doesn't have much, just:
`<p>Click the button to create a new map</p>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Create Map" onclick="updateText();">

<br>

<div id="outputAJAX"></div>`