# Javascript & PHP show multiple trackers in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Currently, I'm developing a system that will bring all latitude and longitude from *MySQLi DB*, and will output every data on the page. Here is my PHP code (working without any problem):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require('database.php');
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `tracking`");
if (!$query)
{
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
    $getList = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
        $getList[] = $row;
    }
    for($i = 0, $l = count($getList); $i < $l; ++$i) {
        echo $getList[$i]['lat'].",".$getList[$i]['lon']."\n";
    }
}
```

e.g output: `-71.99991299555996,-83.18116602 -22.809918399999997,-43.4211132 -22.8540416,-43.2488448`

Now, I need bring all data and put into an array, and put whole latitude/longitude to markers in Google Maps. Check what I have tried:

```
var check = false;
function refreshAll() { // This function will be called every 60 seconds
var locations = [];
locations.length = 0;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "show.php",
    success: function(x)
    {

    var items = x.split("\n");
    for(i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        var data = items[i];
        if ((items[i]).length > 1) {
            locations.push(items[i].trim());
            }
        }

        if (check == false) { // this will avoid map refreshing, I need only markers update.
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 2,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        check = true;
        }

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
            alert(locations[i]);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].trim()),
            map: map
          });
       }
    }
});}
```

The problem is: **the markers is not being set**, and have no errors in console. I'm working on this in the last two days and can't find any solution. Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: What is the content of `locations[i].trim()`?

Comment: locations[i]  is the output from PHP, in this case, the javascript splitted all `\n`.

e.g = locations[0] = -71.99991299555996,-83.18116602

Comment: I have added trim () for debug purposes. Also, I tried `parseFloat (locations [i])` too for the same reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map issue addressing location from DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515074/google-map-issue-addressing-location-from-db)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create map after get information of location through AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120381/create-map-after-get-information-of-location-through-ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here in the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers), the LatLng object is different than the one you are using.
So, replace:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].trim()),
        map: map
      });
```

With

```
locations[i] = locations[i].trim().split(',');
var latLng = {lat: Number(locations[i][0]), lng: Number(locations[i][1])};

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: latLng,
             map: map
         });
```

Comment: I'm getting now this error: `setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`

Comment: What's in `lat` that is not a number?

Comment: Is a number, maybe PHP is showing as string, and the javascript is getting as string too, is this possible?

Comment: `alert(locations[i][0])` is returning a number

Comment: Updated.. use `Number` to cast the value

Answer (score 0):

Check out, the map object is in your infoWindow variable, try to set there the positions. 
This should be used inside the locations loop.

```
var pos = {
   lat: latitude,
   lng: longitude
};

infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
```

Comment: Are you talking about `infoWindow.setPosition(locations[i]);`? I tried this way, and I got this error: `setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object`

Comment: Ok, can you console the value of locations[i]? Try to add splitted,
use like this: 
lat : parseFloat( locations.latitude )
lng: parseFloat( locations.longitude)

Comment: @Karlna to check out the variable type, use typeof. This parameters have to be number. Your location array also should have this format: location = { lat: 999, lng:999 }